# Why when I add an alert() does default behavior return after preventDefault() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to prevent default so I can do other things. Just to see if it worked, I added an alert.

Html/jquery:

```
<p><label for="value_new">Add </label><input class="suggest noSubmit" id="value_new" type="text" /></p>

$(document).on("keydown",".noSubmit",
    function() {
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();             
                //return false;
                alert("it worked");
            }
    }
);
```

But when I close the alert, the form gets submitted. If I use `console.log("it worked")` instead, the form is not submitted.

Is my alert being interpreted as a confirmation for the default action? And if so, why?

Comment: function needs to take in the event like function(event){...}

Comment: @tabz100 good point, but I saw no difference in behavior with or without `event`, and this still doesn't explain why an `alert()` would change the behavior. Could it be something else?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the event as a parameter to your function

```
$(document).on("keydown",".noSubmit",
    function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();             
                //return false;
                alert("it worked");
            }
    }
);
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Same exact behavior.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Can you post your html so I can take a look?

Comment: @tabz100 I added the target html. There are other jquery functions working on the page, so it's possible something else is interfering. Do you have any idea why adding/removing `event` from the function would make no difference, while `alert()` does?

Comment: @ButtleButkus I'm not sure why adding/removing the event would make no difference. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @tabz100 No errors in console for any of the variations. I tried +event+alert, -event+alert, +event-alert, -event-alert. The presence/absence of `event` in the function argument makes no difference whatsoever. But whenever `alert("it worked")` is there, the form submits.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Are you in the document.ready handler in jQuery? Additionally does your alert appear, or does the form just submit?

Comment: @tabz100 no I'm not in document.ready. My alert appears, and when I press 'OK', the form submits and the page reloads.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to pass in the event to your function:

```
$(document).on("keydown",".noSubmit",
    function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();             
                //return false;
                alert("it worked");
            }
    }
);
```

Comment: Interesting, so why does it work when I don't put in the alert, then?

Comment: AND, when I add in the even into the function, I get the same result. No submit happens unless there is an alert.